# Decorator and class extended

Tags: typescript

What is the difference between decorator and a class extended? 
Maybe the utility is thin ... I use decorator for take informations from class ( entire class with the first parameter of decoration function, his name etc) and I use a class extended for redefine the properties of class or for use them

Thanks

Comment: Read up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842978/decorator-pattern-versus-sub-classing. This is an old, generalized principle that's useful to understand for TypeScript.